# When server GC is ignored?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

I found this in the MSDN article about .NET 4 GC : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx

"Workstation garbage collection is always used on a computer that **has only one processor**, regardless of the  setting. If you specify server garbage collection, the CLR uses workstation garbage collection with concurrency disabled."

I would think that they mean one physical CPU. However I run my app in server GC mode (or at least I thought I did) on a server with one CPU but 8 HT logical processors...

The following code outputs 'true'

```
        System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC
```

So I dont get it - either the following code prints incorrect information or they meant one single core CPU without HT...

Anyone could explain it definitely?

Comment: I thing "on processor" means "one core". Because that is no sense in disable concurrency in GC where you can run more than 1 thread at the same time.

Comment: I'm with @devundef, I think it could be worded better. A CPU core is a "logical processor" as far as Windows is concerned, I suspect this is where the language comes from. When Microsoft refers to physical processors (for example, in licensing) they always say "socket".

Comment: guys write this as an answer. I'll mark it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems the "one processor" refers to a single core no hyper-threading CPU.

Comment: This seems like a bit of an assumption, however it would seem to fit the Windows terminology of mutiple 'logical processors' reported for a single physical processor's 'socket'.