# Server Garbage Collection on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Is it possible to use [Server Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#workstation_and_server_garbage_collection) on Azure App Service?

I have set `gcServer` in the `web.config` (D:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApplication.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But `GCSettings.IsServerGC` still returns false.

Comment: If the app service is [only running with a "single core no hyper-threading CPU"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488324/when-server-gc-is-ignored) then service GC cannot be enabled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.isservergc(v=vs.110).aspx), you could see the remark:

> If server garbage collection is not enabled, workstation garbage collection is in effect (with or without concurrent collection). Server garbage collection is available only on multiprocessor computers.

By default, if your web app service plan is multiprocessor, like B2, S2, it will automatic enabled gcServer.

But if your web app service plan is B1,S1, it only has one core, it will enable workstation.

Here is test example:

I have a page which has below codes:

```
string result;

        if (GCSettings.IsServerGC == true)
            result = "server";
        else
            result = "workstation";

        Response.Write(result);
```

Then I publish the web application to different app service plan.(B1,B2)

The result is as below:

[image]

Comment: Any update? If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply - yes, this solved my issue. I didn't realise the service plan option made a difference.